# 2D Map Creation

Tags: java, 2d, lwjgl

I am new to Map Creation and array storing and was wondering if I could get some assistance in the task. I am working in Java and using the LWJGL library if that is any help at all.

I'm not trying to make a rip off of any other game, so it's going to be different from any other game. I will basically just need different areas, like water, grass and dirt. I'll eventually add mountains and hills and climbing etc.

I need to know how this can be achieved, if it can be, I'm new to it like I said so I don't have any code to give to give you any idea of what level I am at.

If you can help, please leave an answer, would love as much help as I can get too.

Comment: there is another stack that handles these kind of questions ;) http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4031/methods-for-generating-a-map

Comment: No worries, will take a look now. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 4):

How it's rendered (openGL, swing/awt, anything else) isn't related to the map itself. That's just how it's rendered. I use a special CoordinateMap class that I wrote, but it's basically nothing more than a wrapper for `Map<Point,MapTile>`.

How you want your map to be has a big impact on what you're trying to do here. I imagine most of the algorithms will use something like this (assuming rectangular):

```
for(int x = minx; x <= maxx; x++) {
    for(int y = miny; y <= maxy; y++) {
        map.put(new Point(x,y),generateRandomTile());
    }
}
```

Another option you can do is spreading. It works like this:

```
// pick 10 random points (10 is up to you)
MapTile[] seeds = new MapTile[10];
Point[] seedPoints = new Point[seeds.length];
for(int i = 0; i < seeds.length; i++) {
    seeds[i] = generateRandomTile();
    seedPoints[i] = generateRandomPoint();
}

int distance = 1;
while(true) {
    boolean changed = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < seedsPoints.length; i++) {
        Point p = seedPoints[i];
        for(int x = -distance; x <= distance; x++) {
            Point here = new Point(x,p.y));
            MapTile tile = tiles.get(here);
            if(tile == null) {
                 tiles.put(here,new Tile(seeds[i].terrainType));
                 changed = true;
            }
        }
        // that does the left edge of the square of distance away from
        // the center. I'll leave the other edges of the square for you since they're boilerplate
    } // end for seeds
    if(!changed) break;
    distance++;
}
```

Comment: That's excellent help glowcoder. I need further explanation however and was wondering if I can contact you externally some how?

Something like MSN would be appropriate and make it easy to transfer code etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to create games in Java. Creating tile-based levels can also be done in several ways. You may want to do an internet search on some tutorials for creating 2d java games and find some ideas on how to do so.

Since you want to use lwjgl, you will find it difficult to do 2d-based games. There are other frameworks you could use that simplify this for you and the [answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293079/java-2d-game-frameworks) will suggest you some.

Here are some links that may inspire you for making 2d maps:

- [Java Sokoban Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/sokoban/), a simple game to get you going
- [Simple map editor in java](http://code.google.com/p/simple-map-editor/), look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/simple-map-editor/source/browse/#svn/trunk) for inspiration
- [Tiled's file format](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/tiled/index.php?title=TMX_Map_Format) may inspire you on what datastructure to use for your tile maps, [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) is a general purpose 2d map editor by the way

You should also try to use the [game development stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site. They might help you with your game programming efforts as well.